# Recalculate percentage in pixel live?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a fluid percentage-based horizontal grid for my project and like to use the very same vertical margins as my horizontal ones.

So I have something like this:

```
.block_12_24{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
width:48%;
margin-right:2%;
margin-left:0;
/* Now this is what I need to have the very same as the margin-right-value: */
margin-top: 17px; //instead of that
}
```

And now I'd like to have the same values for margin-top as for margin-right. My guess is, that I need to recalculate the 2% into an absolute amount like px and assign that value to margin-top. It's not that important to be checking it all the time, just once initially. Would JavaScript be the only possibility by doing it so:

1. giving the margin-top a roughly fitting value like 17px
2. Letting the page load
3. Checking the browsers width in px via JavaScript
4. var margin= that_amount/50;
5. Manipulating the margin-top of .block_12_24 into that amount

Or could I also do that solely in CSS?
Thanks

Comment: You need window height or document height? If window, try `vh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always make the margin on the window-size base (your document is not horizontally scrollable) you can use viewport percentage values `vw` instead of usual percentage:

```
margin: 2vw;
```

This will set margin for all sides based on the width.

The support of this method across all browsers is [quite good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: But there should be a difference between 2vw and 2vh if the devices' display ain't square? How would I get a relationship between them?

Comment: but I did not propose you to use `vh`. Look at the example again please, I proposed to use `vw` for both vertical and horizontal margins. This will work, just give it a try; this is the main advantage of viewport percentage values: you can refer it in any CSS property and you can choose what to depend on: width or height.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense to use vw both for horizontal and vertical purposes as a a smart hack. This opens quite some new possibilities - thanks for the explanation.